Speed-up matplotlib creation of frame images for animation
I am simulating some physical processes with Python and wish to regularly plot the situation of the system in order to make an animation. What I have been doing so far is to draw a snapshot of the system at regular intervals, save it to file, and finally convert the images into a video using convert or ffmpeg. Lately, however, the plot has been growing in complexity and it takes now 2-3 seconds to generate just one image, which is too long for my needs.
In my system, I have some background elements that are fixed and never change, and some other elements that are subject to movements depending on time. As a minimum working example, consider the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time


class MWE():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.imageCounter = 0
        self.elapsed_time = 0.0

    def evolve(self):
        theta = 2 * np.pi * self.elapsed_time
        self.x = np.cos(theta)
        self.y = np.sin(theta)
        self.elapsed_time += self.dt

    def draw(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2), layout='constrained')
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.axis('off')

        ax.set_xlim((-2, 2))
        ax.set_ylim((-2.2, 2))

        for center_x in np.linspace(-2,2, 21)[1::2]:
            for center_y in np.linspace(-2,2, 21)[1::2]:
                blue_circle = plt.Circle((center_x, center_y), 0.1, color='blue', fill=False)
                ax.add_patch(blue_circle)

        red_circle = plt.Circle((self.x, self.y), 0.1, color='red', fill=True)
        ax.add_patch(red_circle)
        self.imageCounter += 1

        ax.text(-1.9, -2.2, f'Time: {self.elapsed_time:.2f} s', color='black', size=8)

        fig.savefig(f'MWE_{str(self.imageCounter).zfill(3)}.png')
        plt.clf()
        plt.cla()
        plt.close()


mwe = MWE()

start_time = time.time()
while mwe.elapsed_time < 1.0:
    mwe.evolve()
    mwe.draw()
print(f"Execution: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s" % ())

convert -resize 100% -delay 2 -loop 0 MWE_*.png loop.gif


The execution on my computer takes Execution: 51.32 s, therefore I am looking for alternative way to handle the plots, be it keeping in memory the background drawing, or using an additional package for the animation.

Did you try blitting?  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/blitting.html

Note you can also just change the position of the red circle and not redraw all the blue circles.  See set_data

matplotlib is inherently slow and IMHO not really suited for animations. I can certainly be significantly faster than that (2 second is pretty big), but the best I got with several tries was generally disappointing (even for relatively simple scenes, it was not able to reach >10 FPS).

Generating png is rather slow because the file needs to be compressed using the relatively-expensive lossless inflate algorithm (LZ77 like). You can try bmp ones though it will take a significant space on the storage device. I think jpg files should be faster than png though certainly slower than bmp (regarding your hardware).

If you only aim for exporting images, switch to the agg backend (matplotlib.use("agg") to avoid initializing and destroying a gui for each figure

Without any fancy blitting (which probably speeds up things even more dramatically), these few simple changes bring execution time down to Execution: 4.10 s on my side:

initialize figure only once
draw artists only once and update positions
switch to agg backend to avoid unnecessary guis


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

plt.switch_backend("agg")

class MWE():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.imageCounter = 0
        self.elapsed_time = 0.0
        
        self.init_figure()

    def init_figure(self):
        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2), layout='constrained')
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.axis('off')

        ax.set_xlim((-2, 2))
        ax.set_ylim((-2.2, 2))

        for center_x in np.linspace(-2,2, 21)[1::2]:
            for center_y in np.linspace(-2,2, 21)[1::2]:
                blue_circle = plt.Circle((center_x, center_y), 0.1, color='blue', fill=False)
                ax.add_patch(blue_circle)

        self.red_circle = plt.Circle((self.x, self.y), 0.1, color='red', fill=True)
        ax.add_patch(self.red_circle)
        self.info_text = ax.text(-1.9, -2.2, f'Time: {self.elapsed_time:.2f} s', color='black', size=8)

    def evolve(self):
        theta = 2 * np.pi * self.elapsed_time
        self.x = np.cos(theta)
        self.y = np.sin(theta)
        self.elapsed_time += self.dt

    def draw(self):
        self.red_circle.set_center((self.x, self.y))
        self.info_text.set_text(f'Time: {self.elapsed_time:.2f} s')
        self.imageCounter += 1

        self.fig.savefig(f'MWE_{str(self.imageCounter).zfill(3)}.png')


mwe = MWE()
mwe.init_figure()

# %%
start_time = time.time()
while mwe.elapsed_time < 1.0:
    mwe.evolve()
    mwe.draw()
print(f"Execution: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s" % ())


